# CSS: How to extend footer all the way to bottom of page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how do you extend the footer all the way to the bottom of the page so it covers up all the white space?

[Live link](http://ogmda.com/si2s/)

```
<div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="images/logo_footer.png" class="logo_footer"> <small>&copy; 2014 by SI2S, LLC. All rights reserved.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If one of these answers has benefited you, please accept an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%; /* needed for container min-height */
}


div#pageContainer {
    position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height: 100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
}


div#content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; /* bottom padding for footer */
}

div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
}
```

Then:

```
<div id="pageContainer">

    <div id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- or whatever column spec -->
                    <!-- header content here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- or whatever column spec -->
                    <!-- main page content here -->
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- or whatever column spec -->
                    <!-- footer content here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add your footer css file following code:

```
.footer-bottom
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately none of the solutions posted in this page have worked:( Another ideas?

Comment: Can you send me the files ffot that website so i can tesst and turn back to you?

Answer (score 1):

```
html,body {
   height: 100%
}
.footer-bottom {
   position:relative;
   bottom:0;
}
```

in some cases containers for the footer should have `height:100%` too

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.footer-bottom {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```